# How do I remove URL in webview screen for Azure AD B2C login

Tags: .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

I am using Azure AD B2C for login in a Xamarin Forms IOS and Android app. With Azure AD B2C, it will redirect you to `login.microsoftonline.com` url. Since the `<tenant>.loginb2c.com` is still in preview, I was trying to see if I could customize the webview screen to remove the url.

Here is a link to a channel9 video that shows what I am trying to accomplish with the Real Madrid app, [Channel9 Azure AD B2C video](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Mechanics/Azure-AD-B2C-How-to-enable-consumer-logins-and-access-management-for-your-B2C-apps/player#time=9m0s:paused)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not currently possible.

Please see [the FAQ for Azure B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs):

> **Can I use my own URLs on my sign-up and sign-in pages that are served by Azure AD B2C? For instance, can I change the URL from
>   login.microsoftonline.com to login.contoso.com?**
>
> ---
>
> Not currently. This feature is on our roadmap. Verifying your domain
>   in the Domains tab in the Azure portal does not accomplish this goal.

You can, however, upvote the feature request and subscribe to [AAD product feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15334317-customer-owned-domains) to be notified when this feature is available.

Comment: Thanks, but do you know how the Action Bar in the app in the video was changed so that the URL is not shown?